# svn+ssh ignores ssh key, and won't accept password - why?

Tags: svn, ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

I’m setting up an Ubuntu 10.04.4 machine to pull over a Rails app from a Subversion repository on a remote server.

I’ve set up the ssh key authentication, and that works fine for login – I can ssh from my Ubuntu box to the remote machine where the repository resides, as the appropriate user, without being prompted for the password.

However, my capified Rails app install fails when attempting to run a subversion command via svn+ssh.

I’ve tried running a similar svn command directly on the Ubuntu box, and see the same problem.

Not only does this prompt me for the password (ignoring the key), but it also won’t accept the password when entered manually.

```
rails@mubuntubox-001:~$ svn info —username scm_user —password XXXXXXX svn+ssh://scm.mydomain.co.uk/Users/Shared/Repositories/doodle_svn
Password:
Password:
Password:
svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

I believe this is the same problem the Rails app installation hits.

Any hints as to what is causing the svn+ssh key / password access to be rejected would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, file this one under 'Misleading error messages'.

The problem was [or seems to be] that the svn parameter --username isn't the one used to set up the ssh connection.  So, it was defaulting to my local user, which doesn't exist on my SVN server.

Specifying the user in the svn+ssh (as follows) fixed this...

```
svn info —username scm_user —password XXXXXXX svn+ssh://scm_user@scm.mydomain.co.uk/Users/Shared/Repositories/doodle_svn
```

Comment: To debug such things, you can configure the ssh client to show debug messages. Easyest way is to add the "LogLevel DEBUG1" in the "Host *" section of the ~/.ssh/config file. Or in the related section of the host if you have. Then you should see all the details about the ssh connection.